# What does "less the" mean?

Tags: notation

What is the symbolic meaning of `current high less the current low`?

Is it the min, difference, or something else?

Comment: This is used as opposite for the word plus. "The prize of the book is $100 less the discount": meaning $100 is the marked prize and discount is to be applied.

Comment: @PVanchinathan thank you! Subtraction it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this that I have seen, "less" refers to subtraction. I have seen old arithmetic books and worksheets that didn't use any symbolic notation, with statements like, "Eight and four, less seven, is five" meaning $8+4-7=5$.

I don't know the context of your statement, so I can't say for sure. However, presumably the "current high" is greater than or equal to the "current low," so if the statement means the minimum, then it is trivial. So I think that meaning is unlikely.